# Nuxt Crashed while using a big html file content

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt js` to create a `Universal (SSR)` Web app, 
When i put a big html file content in a component or wherever it crashes.

All folders in `.nuxt` folder removed and the compiler stopped, also when stop and retry run `npm run dev` the server opened in a random port not the default one `:3000`, and nothing changed.

Comment: we are going to need a lot more context than just `when I put a big html file content in a component` - what does it contain. Where are you putting it. Is it making any changes? Does it have specific tags that are overriding. Is this a freshly made `nuxt` app?

Comment: reproduciton or nooone will help you